# Style overriding

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have written a new style for my button (width, height, alignment), but I also use ExpressionDark style and when I use MY style like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
...
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
```

... it overrides ExpressionDark style:/ How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

[`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx)`="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"`

Comment: @Nickon: When do you set the theme? This should base your style on the theme style by referencing the global implicit style for buttons.

Comment: In App.xaml in Application.Resources I have these 2 lines:                  <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\Skins\ExpressionDark.xaml" /> <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\WindowStyle.xaml" />

Comment: @Nickon: That sounds quite static to me so i would expect StaticResource to pick up the theme's style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property in order to extend from an existing style.

```
 <Style x:Key="Style1">
   <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
 </Style>

 <Style x:Key="Style2" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
 </Style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, don't know why (I used that before I wrote this post)